# Mutating NSDictionary inside NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsarray, nsdictionary

Is there any quick way of mutating a NSArray of NSDictionaries? I have a big NSArray and I want to update the value for a particular key inside the NSDictionary. Is there any quick way of mutating the inner dictionaries so that I could update them.

Comment: A for-in loop perhaps?

Comment: Are the dictionaries mutable or not? Do you want to update one particular array element, or *all* dictionaries with that key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your original array contains immutable dictionaries then one way is to create a new array with mutable copies of all of the original dictionaries.

```
NSMutableArray *newArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:oldArray.count];
for (NSDictionary *dict in oldArray) {
    [newArray addObject:[dict mutableCopy]];
}
```

Now do all of your work on `newArray`.

Comment: Thank you. I think this is the only option. I was expecting that there would be some direct way of doing this.

Comment: Do note that if the original structure is coming from JSON there is an option for NSJSONSerialization that will give you mutable arrays and indexes.

Comment: (Otherwise I'd be tempted to create `deepMutableCopy` categories for NSArray and NSDictionary.)

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want to modify all of the dictionaries simultaneously.  Your dictionaries need to be `NSMutableDictionary` instances if you want to modify them.

Assuming they are, you can modify all of them simultaneously using `setValue:forKey:`.  Example:

```
static NSMutableDictionary *dictionary() {
    return [@{ @"first": @"Oscar", @"second": @"Meyer" } mutableCopy];
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSArray *array = @[ dictionary(), dictionary(), dictionary() ];
        [array setValue:@"Humphrey" forKey:@"first"];
        NSLog(@"%@", array);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The below code will change a particular dictionary and return your NSArray instance.
For below example `arrayOfDictionaries` is original array which contains all objects.

```
NSDictionary *dic1 = @{@"key":@"object1"};
NSDictionary *dic2 = @{@"key":@"object2"};
NSDictionary *dic3 = @{@"key":@"object3"};

NSArray *arrayOfDictionaries=@[dic1,dic2,dic3];
NSMutableArray *mutableArray =[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:arrayOfDictionaries];

//suppose you want to modify dic2

NSInteger index=[arrayOfDictionaries indexOfObject:dic2];
//index will be 1

NSMutableDictionary *mutableDic =[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:dic2];
[mutableDic setObject:@"objectChanged" forKey:@"key"];
NSDictionary *changedDic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:mutableDic];
[mutableArray replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:changedDic];

arrayOfDictionaries = [NSArray arrayWithArray:mutableArray];
NSLog(@"%@",arrayOfDictionaries[1]);
```

**LOGS**

```
{
    key = objectChanged;
}
```